# Argparse to convert argument list to space delimited string

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Short sample app')

parser.add_argument('-a',nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args(['-a', '1', '4'])
print(args.a)
```

Prints a list of strings ['1', '4'] but I need `args.a` to be a space delimited string i.e. '1 4'. How can that be done?

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be parsing anything from the command line

Comment: Honestly, I would recommend that `-a` simply take a single space-delimited  argument rather than joining them yourself. `parse_args(['-a', '1 4'])`. This places a minimal burden on the user.

Answer (score 2):

After using `parse_args`, use the `string.join(iterable)` method where string is `' '`, and assign the result to `args.a`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Short sample app')

parser.add_argument('-a',nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args(['-a', '1', '4'])

# in practice, check if -a is set
if args.a is not None:
    args.a = " ".join(args.a)

# later ...

if args.a is not None:
    print('"%s"' % args.a)
```

> ```
> "1 4"
> ```

Comment: This is not an answer to my question as args.a does not have the desired value.

Comment: I thought the title was clear. It says "Argparse to convert argument list to space delimited string"

Comment: @user2672165 It wasn't clear. "Convert" by itself doesn't specify whether the original value is overwritten or not. Even the python docs say the input is  "converted" when [talking about](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) `bool`, a function that converts a value without modifying the input.  Anyway, did the edit to this answer address your concerns?